# Phantomjs + selenium+ testNG is not loading the Inner HTML Content of angular2

Tags: angular, selenium, phantomjs

```
@Test
public void openBrowser()  {

    File src = new File("H:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            caps.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            src.getAbsolutePath());

  PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8080/");

    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

driver.findElement( By.id("login-reg")).click();

```
}
```

when i run this, this is not loading the actual content ...

Loading...

And the same code work normally if i dont use PhantomJS.
and the same error with HTMLUnitDriver also...

If i try to use Headless Browser I am getting this problem
please Help Me.

Thank you

Comment: <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

Comment: It is not loading the Original content thats why the element is not clickable